# Serialization and messaging framework for C

Tags: c, sockets, message-queue, messaging

Currently for IPC we are using CLIENT/SERVER architecture with UNIX DOMAIN sockets, TLV packet format and ENCODE/DECODE functions for every variable in a structure to be serialized. Even though current framework works, adding new processes written in other programming languages is painful. I want to automate and generate code for encode/decode functions for every message between CLIENT/SERVER so that the logic is less error prone for future implementations.

I have thought about APACHE THRIFT. But current APACHE THRIFT implementation for C does not support auto generation of code and user has to manually code the skeleton logic. Since my primary language is C, Is there any library or framework where I can achieve APACHE THRIFT kind of messaging framework in C?

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted the question ?

Comment: Me neither, but I understand that requests to recommend a library are specifically banned. I most cases I can understand why that is but, in this case, your question seems perfectly reasonable and apposite. Sorry I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a C implementation of Google Protocol Buffers.
You define messages and services and protobuf generates the code.
See https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c